# Ошибка миграции БД: такая таблица уже существует

Tags: laravel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при миграций бд говорит то что такая таблица уже существует хотя должна показывать в my-sql еще три таблицы
В my-sql таблица migtations пуста

https://i.stack.imgur.com/904ND.png

Comment: У Вас 2 миграции с одинаковым названием класса. Классы в миграциях должны называться уникально. Из-за этого и ошибка.

Comment: спасибо большое